# How to ignore URL parameters in Cucumber paths.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, dynamic, cucumber

In my support/paths.rb file, one of my case clauses is:

```
when /the checkout page/ then '/store/checkout'
```

However, in some flows, a redirect to the checkout page adds some parameters to the URL, so that the redirect is not to '/store/checkout' but to (e.g.) '/store/checkout?email_confirmation=1'.

The problem is that this causes some assertions to fail with Cucumber, such as line 3 below:

```
Given I am on the checkout page
When I proceed with a blank email address
Then I should be on the checkout page
And I should see "You must provide an email address."
```

Step 3 fails with:

```
   Then I should be on the checkout page                              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:185
  expected: "/store/checkout",
       got: "/store/checkout?email_confirmation=1" (using ==)
```

How can I get Cucumber to ignore the parameters after '?' in the redirected URL?

`Then I should be on the checkout page`

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but paths.rb is part of cucumber-rails-training-wheels not cucumber. I've investigated this a little, and it seems that the current behavior should match what you expected. Maybe play around with the code from web_steps.rb in the console? Or maybe it's time to update ruby/gems?

Comment: On second thought, this used to be part of `cucumber-rails` before this: http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off I suppose I should have taken a minute to study my computer history.

Comment: Yep, this is an old project so it's still using a version of Cuke before the 'training wheels' came off.  (0.6.4!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the answer (which is kind of deep in the comments) is to do one of the following:

1. Update to new `cucumber-rails-training-wheels` which contains the expected behavior.
2. Ensure that `web_steps.rb` is correctly setting the `current_path` variable.

   ```
   current_path = URI.parse(current_url).path
   ```

   instead of this:

   ```
   current_path = URI.parse(current_url).select(:path, :query).compact.join('?')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I followed Geoff's advice and solved this by modifying web_steps.rb.  Specifically, in the canned step definition

```
Then /^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
```

I changed this assertion

```
current_path.should == path_to(page_name)
```

to this, which compares only the part of the URL before any '?...' parameter strings:

```
current_path.gsub(/\?.*$/, '').should == path_to(page_name).gsub(/\?.*$/, '')
```

Comment: In the separated gem version of training wheels, this line in web_steps.rb does what you wanted: `current_path = URI.parse(current_url).path`. I wonder if the old version doesn't work the same way or if that line is missing? P.S. Thank you for introducing me to rails.

Comment: Huh.  In the old version that line is: `current_path = URI.parse(current_url).select(:path, :query).compact.join('?')`  which explicitly **includes** the URL parameters in the match.  I consider that a bug, so the answer here is "upgrade to latest cucumber-rails-training-wheels".